# i am trying to delete ext4.vhdx in Docker wsl file

Tags: docker, wsl-2, ext4, diskpart

> "DISKPART> attach vdisk readonly
> Virtual Disk Service error: The virtual disk is already attached."

it is not turning disk into readonly.

i tried diskpart commands but its throwing some error.

Comment: Please add the steps you tried and the Dockerfile

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.